# mongorestore: command not found while running

Tags: mongodb, environment-variables, mongorestore

Same situation:
I have started the M101 MongoDB online course. The restoremongo call returns mongorestore: command not found. This should connect to the server(Which I can connect to and is running on my machine). I am simply following this video(link below) to the point at 1:45 minutes into the video. https://education.10gen.com/courses/10gen/M101J/2013_May/courseware/Week_1_-_Introduction/Homework_1.1/

This is where I am at; please see below. I have copied and pasted the server info beneath this. Any solutions? I'd be most grateful. Gerry

tar xvf hw1-1.957cdceb1c1e.tar 
x dump/
x dump/m101/
x dump/m101/funnynumbers.bson
x dump/m101/funnynumbers.metadata.json
x dump/m101/hw1.bson
x dump/m101/hw1.metadata.json
Geralds-MacBook-Pro:Downloads geraldnolan$ mongorestore
-bash: mongorestore: command not found

I have my environment variable set to export PATH=$PATH:/Users/bluegenep/Downloads/mongodb-osx-x86_64-2.4.8/bin

and my path where mongodb lies is "/Users/bluegenep/Downloads/mongodb-osx-x86_64-2.4.8/bin"

But I am still getting the same error!!

-bash: mongorestore: command not found

Any help will be much appreciated! Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

Check and see if you can run the mongorestore application from inside the bin directory, the possible error is that the path is not set correctly, there was a similar question about the exact same thing couple of months ago.

[mongodb-mongorestore-command-not-found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17041337/mongodb-mongorestore-command-not-found)